# C Program which checks multiple numbers from user input and prints out if they are prime or not

Tags: c

I am a newbie programmer and just started to teach myself C then decided to tackle some simple problems taken from the internet. Specifically with this one: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmV2F.png)

And my solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int n, i, test = 0;
  char s[] = "";
  do{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 1){
      break;
    }

    for(i = 2; i <= n/2; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
        test = 1;
        break;
        }
    }

    if(test == 0){
        **s[] += "%d IS PRIME\n", n;**
    }
    else{
        **s[] += "%d IS NOT PRIME\n", n;**
    }

    }while(i > 1);
  printf("%s", s);
  return 0;
}
```

However, the current problem I have is modifying my program so that it would print out like the expected results (see output from Problem). And for this, I would need to concatenate the results each time into a string variable where it would be printed last, after the user inputs 1 or a number lesser than 1 which would terminate the program. I have decent experience with Java and I have highlighted that part in this program. Basically, what would be the most logical way to write that part as a C command?

Comment: I recommend that you find a good (or even mediocre) book or tutorial to learn a few things about strings in C. Perhaps even take a class. You should do that because you make many mistakes with strings here in this little program.

Comment: Tip, when `n` is large `for(i = 2; i <= n/i; i++){` will run faster than `for(i = 2; i <= n/2; i++){`.

Comment: The first thing to understand is that C strings never resize themselves. That has all sorts of consequences that the code needs to handle. So I agree with Someprogrammerdude that you need to study C strings before you attempt to use C strings.

Comment: Recommend checking the return value of `scanf`, `if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) break;` and possibly checking `errno` if this happened. This will make your code robust to piping, eof, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Move the print statement into the while loop so it is done each iteration of the loop.

test needs to be reset back to 0 in each loop iteration before doing the test for prime.

In addition the **s[] is not doing what you think it is. Remove it, and change it so that it prints the results at that point:

```
if(test == 0){
  printf("%d is PRIME\n", n);
}
else {
  printf("%d is NOT PRIME\n", n);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, it is not supposed to run and print the output statements simultaneously. It is supposed to take in the numbers and print out all of the statements at the same time after the program finishes running

Comment: The problem does not specify that - it just provides inputs and what the output will be.